# Are both "numpy.ndim(<array_name>)" and "<array_name>.ndim" correct?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

NUMPY
I want to know whether
"numpy.ndim(<array_name>)" and "<array_name>.ndim" means the same thing.
Can both the syntax be used?

Comment: One shows a property of the array.  The other is a function that first makes sure the argument is an array (it will work on a list)

Comment: It seems the documentation for `numpy.ndim` is not available online, but the result of this function with built-in scalars and enumerables is shown the in the [documentation for `numpy.isscalar()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isscalar.html#numpy-isscalar).

Answer (score 0):

As is common in `numpy` the function version first makes sure the argument is an array, and then applies the method or attribute version.

```
In [16]: np.ndim([[1,2,3]])
Out[16]: 2

In [17]: np.array([[1,2,3]]).ndim
Out[17]: 2
```

The function code:

```
Signature: np.ndim(a)
Source:   
@array_function_dispatch(_ndim_dispatcher)
def ndim(a):
    """
    Return the number of dimensions of an array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        Input array.  If it is not already an ndarray, a conversion is
        attempted.

    Returns
    -------
    number_of_dimensions : int
        The number of dimensions in `a`.  Scalars are zero-dimensional.

 ....
    """
    try:
        return a.ndim
    except AttributeError:
        return asarray(a).ndim
File:      c:\users\14256\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py
Type:      function
```